# ReactJS - LocalStorage, how do I format my localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an app that saves items in a list to another list that is then passed, using JSON, to the localstorage and then that localstorage information has to be retrieved from another page, the thing is that the information comes like this

```
{"name":"Red Dress","image":"/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png","Price":120,"id":1}
```

while I want it to come in a format that is like this

```
Name: "Red Dress",
Image: "/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png",
Price: 120,
id: 1
```

And the reason I want it to come like this is so that, later on, I could point to this data as **{product.Name**} and it would give me **"Red Dress"**, **{product.Price}** and it would give me **120** etc.
Here's the corresponding code, that is where I set the localstorage and declare the useState that would keep the items and add them to a differnet list that is added to the localStorage:

```
const addItem=(item)=>
{
    setProduct([...product, item])
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.parse(product))
}
const[product, setProduct] = useState([])
const [item]=useState([
    {
        name: 'Blue Dress',
        image: '/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png',
        Price: 200,
        id: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Red Dress',
        image: '/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png',
        Price: 120,
        id: 1
    },

])
```

And this is the corresponding code on the page that retrieves the data

```
    const [product, getProduct]= useState([])
const getProducts=()=>
{
    let X = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('products'))
    getProduct([...product, X])
}
```

Since I have forgotten to add my map function that shows the objects in question, here it is:

```
{product.map(item=>
            <div>
                    <h3 className='productName'>{item.name}</h3>
                    <div className='productImageContainer'>
                        <img  className='productImage'src={item.image}></img>

                    </div>
                    <span className='productPrice'><strong>${item.Price}.00</strong></span>
                    <Button className='removeProductButton' variant='danger'><MdCancel></MdCancel> Remove</Button>
                    <br></br>
            </div>)}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use map and build the objects the way you want ?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but it doesn't really give me anything, it returns undefined

Comment: localStorage save data as string, if you want the data as a JSON you should use `JSON.parse()`.

Its good to say that if you have so many operations with localStorage maybe its a good idea to replace localStorage to IndexDB.

Comment: But the thing is I did use JSON.parse() and it still returns the data as a string, that's why I came here asking for clarification

Comment: You have `stringify` and `parse` flipped. You `stringify` to set local storage and `parse` when you get local storage.

Comment: I've already tried flipping the stringify and parse but it was to no avail, the result is the same